# How to colour text in StaticText (wxpython) in different colours?

Tags: python, wxpython

Is it somehow possible to have text of a StaticText field in wxpython coloured in different colours? I know you can change the colour of the whole text (value) of a StaticText field like this:

```
text = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'random text')
text.SetForegroundColour('blue')
```

But how can I have the a text coloured in different colours, for example 'random' coloured in red and 'text' coloured in blue. Is there a way? Or is there some kind of other widget I could use?

Answer (score 1):

The wx.StaticText widget doesn't support that sort of thing. You'd want to use one of the StyledText controls instead. the RichText control would probably work too.

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
text.SetForegroundColour((255,0,0)) # set text color
text.SetBackgroundColour((0,0,255)) # set text back color
```

*the colors are in RGB format.
You can find a list of them [here](http://www.tayloredmktg.com/rgb/). Replace the numbers I have put in with whatever color you want.

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for quick reply. The problem is I want to colour the text differently. 'text.SetBackgroundColour()' only changes the colour of the StaticText field background... 'text.SetForegroundColour()' changes the text colour but it seem you can only change it to one uniform colour... Do you know what I mean? I would like to have the text in different colours though...

Comment: I think I get you. the only simple way I can think of is simple splitting the text object into several objects, making each part your chosen color and then printing them together.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought of too but that could get quite complex... Well basically what I need it for is for a search in a list of different titles. The typed in search term should be coloured in the different titles/names. So for example if I have a list of "Apple, Pear, Banana, Peach, Strawberry" if I start typing "Pe" the 'pe' of pear and peach should be coloured in a different colour than the others...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late to the party but maybe it helps someone.

Depending on what platform you are under you could use the method `SetLabelMarkup` which allow using HTML-like tags. It doesn't work on Windows but on some Linux versions.

For example, if you want a bi-colored text you can write

```
text.SetLabelMarkup('<span foreground=\'red\'>Hello, </span><span foreground=\'blue\'>World</span>
```

The documentation can be found [here](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Control.html#wx.Control.SetLabelMarkup)

[Picture: Result on Raspbian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXKka.png)