# How to have different colored texts in a wx.StaticText() in wxPython

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

Level: Beginner

I am developing a GUI with wxPython on Windows 7 OS. I have a question regarding the `wx.StaticText()`
I would like to have two different colors for a text in a `wx.StaticText()` field.
How can I achieve that?

For eg: As shown in the image below I need two different parts of a text to have two different colors.
[image]

I tried to separate the text into two parts and then applied different colors to them but for some reason the first text fields doesn't appears only second one appears in the GUI. I even tried to use `pos=()` in `wx.StaticText()` and other options but nothing worked.
In my code I am creating panels in a loop and then inside the loop I am creating `wx.StaticText()` fields and adding them to a panel. When the loop completes these panels are ultimately added to a BoxSizer.

The code snippet is given below (Please be advised that I have edited the code below from my actual code. My main idea is to know if my approach will solve this problem or not? My code is working fine for one wx.StaticText field, which prints the values in the panels in a same color.):

```
k = 0
sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
for i in locations: #locations is defined in other part of the code
    lPanels = 'lPanel'+str(k)
    lPanels = wx.Panel(panel2, size=(screenWidth,50))
    #panel2 and screenWidth are defined in other part of code.
    label0 = str(k+1)+ '. '
    label1 = locations[k]
    text0 = wx.StaticText(lPanels, -1, label0)
    text0.SetForegroundColour('#ffffff')
    text1 = wx.StaticText(lPanels, -1, label1)
    text1.SetForegroundColour('#000001')
    sizer.Add(lPanels, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
    k += 1
panel2.SetSizer(sizer)
```

Is there a better way to approach this problem? Can some one provide a small example? Thank you.
PS: There is a similar kind of an old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420088/how-to-colour-text-in-statictext-wxpython-in-different-colours). But it is not answered yet.

Comment: should "text.setforeground" be text1.setforground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your "text1" overlap "text0", that is why "the first text fields doesn't appears only second one appears in the GUI" as you said

Please try this:

```
    text0 = wx.StaticText(lPanels, -1, label0, pos=(0,0))
    text0.SetForegroundColour('BLACK')
    text1 = wx.StaticText(lPanels, -1, label1, pos=(50,0))
    text1.SetForegroundColour('BLUE')
```

EDIT:

Please check the value of "screenWidth", make sure its width is big enough to contain all the string.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, As I already mentioned in my post that I have already tried pos=(). Unfortunately when I use pos=() neiher of the texts appears. Also as I am adding the panels in a loop shouldn't that be a problem, because it maybe adding panels on the same point while using pos=()

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I think I posted a wrong question. The actual problem in my was that I was not using absolute positioning(In my programme the text, panels etc. are added automatically by the programme itself.) So, the texts overlapped. I finally figured out a solution for that. I have to use sizers and then add these two different texts to a sizers and so on... Anyways thanks. :)